# How to find the last element of ng-content when testing with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I need to find and click the always last element. this is what when I inspect.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if below locator works for you.

`element.all(by.css('.ng-star-inserted')).last();`

This gives you the last `div` instance

Comment: No It is not working for me giving me an Error  `No element found using locator: By(css selector, .ng-star-inserted:last-child)`

Comment: I have tried `element(by.css('#viewServiceStatus > app-heartbeat-status-icon > div:last-child'))` Which clicks on the First result **more than one element found for locator By(css selector, #viewServiceStatus > app-heartbeat-status-icon > div:last-child) - the first result will be used** can anybody help me out to Click on the last element and get the Color of the last element

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe I have updated my answer, please check.

Comment: I have tried this gives me an error **element not visible**

Comment: The div is under the `<mat-cell _ngcontent-c17="" class="mat-cell cdk-column-heartbeats mat-column-heartbeats ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell">` till this is open the div element wont be visible but how to get the above element